# Client side mongodb-like queries in backbone

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Is there a way to check whether an object is matched by a mongodb-type query on the client side? For instance:

```
function is_matched(obj,query){
  ...something magic here...
}

var potato = {val:1}

is_matched(potato,{val:1})
```

returns true, and

```
is_matched(potato,{foo:bar})
```

returns false.

The tricky part is that I'd like for it to take the same kinds of queries as mongodb so that you can do more complicated things like regular expressions and the like. Is there something on the client side that will emulate mongo's query matching behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Loki.js http://lokijs.org/#/ it is an in-memory no-sql database with a mongodb like query syntax (it works on browser as well)

and here's how your current example can be mimicked using loki.js :

```
db = new loki('loki.json')
children = db.addCollection('children')
children.add({val: 1})

children.find({val: 1}) // returns [{val: 1}]
children.find({foo: "bar"}) // returns [] (empty collection)
```